# visual studio copy selected (in designer)control name to paste into text editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

is there a way to quick copy selected control name to paste it then to text editor? i have lot of control that i have to set my class property to, then i have to select each one then click on properties, then select name and ctrl+C. Is there no way to just select control on designer then ctrl+C+someOtherKey end voila i can paste it to text editor ? (or even maybe there is a way to quick copy of name of all selected contols :) ?

I use visual studio proffesional 2012 (going to change it to 2015 in near future).

Comment: got to the className.designer.cs u will see the code there ..

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create my own custom extention. Say for example that you want all your Buttons to be green and say "Zelda". You would create the following class.

```
public GreenZeldaButton : Button
{
    public GreenZeldaButton()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Green;
        Text = "Zelda";
    }
}
```

Then you have to get this into the Toolbox, I'm not sure of the proper method but what I do is create a new instance in the form contructor. As so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new GreenZeldaButton();
    }
}
```

And then press F5 to debug in order to add the new control to the toolbox. Then you can drag and drop the new control from the toolbox to the Designer. This is what I do when I want multiple copies of a control with specific properties. Hope this helps ^_^. P.S. You can remove the "new GreenZeldaButton();" thing (or your alternative obviously) after the control has been added to the toolbox.

[image: Example of concept]